# Filter WPF C# DataGrid with textbox with sql query

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, filter

Users,

perhaps someone of you can help me in a problem. I searched all information in stackoverflow and many other google sites, but didn't find a good answer. My problem is I want to filter a DataGrid in WPF with a textbox. I put in text in my textbox but nothing happens. The DataGrid shows an Access Datatable which is calling from a connection string. All the column names are in the Access Database, there aren't Columns or datasets in the code.

My Code:

```
    OleDbConnection con;
    DataTable dt;
```

// ...

```
    private void BindGrid()
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from KundenTab";
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dgvKunde.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
        con.Close();

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dgvKunde.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            dgvKunde.DataContext = dt;
            con.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            dgvKunde.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            con.Close();
        }
        countRows();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\ShopDB.accdb";
        BindGrid();
    }
```

// Textchangedevent:

```
    private void txtSuche_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSuche.Text))
        {
            (dgvKunde.DataContext as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            //(datagrid.DataContext as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("name LIKE '%{0}%' AND vorname LIKE '%{1}%'", txtSearching.Text, txtSearch_C.Text);
            (dgvKunde.DataContext as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("VorName LIKE '%{0}%'" +
                "                                                                    OR NachName LIKE '%{0}%' " +
                "                                                                    OR Strasse LIKE '%{0}%' " +
                "                                                                    OR PLZ LIKE '%{0}%' " +
                "                                                                    OR AlterPerson LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSuche.Text);
        }
```

// XAML

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txbVorname" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,12,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Vorname" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Foreground="#FF897676" GotFocus="txbVorname_GotFocus" LostFocus="txbVorname_LostFocus"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txbStrasse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,96,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Strasse" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Foreground="#FF897676" GotFocus="txbStrasse_GotFocus" LostFocus="txbStrasse_LostFocus"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txbAlter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,68,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Alter" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Foreground="#FF897676" GotFocus="txbAlter_GotFocus" LostFocus="txbAlter_LostFocus"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txbNachname" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,40,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Nachname" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Foreground="#FF897676" GotFocus="txbNachname_GotFocus" LostFocus="txbNachname_LostFocus"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txbPLZ" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,124,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="PLZ" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Foreground="#FF897676" GotFocus="txbPLZ_GotFocus" LostFocus="txbPLZ_LostFocus"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txbMail" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="10,152,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Mail" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Foreground="#FF897676" GotFocus="txbMail_GotFocus" LostFocus="txbMail_LostFocus"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txbPassword" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="10,181,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Foreground="#FF897676" GotFocus="txbPassword_GotFocus" LostFocus="txbPassword_LostFocus"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="Anlegen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" Height="63" Click="btnAdd_Click"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgvKunde" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="206,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="424" SelectionChanged="dgvKunde_SelectionChanged" LoadingRow="dgvKunde_LoadingRow">
    </DataGrid>

    <TextBox x:Name="txtID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="10,210,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="ID_Kunde" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsEnabled="False"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnEdit" Content="Ändern" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,103,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" Height="63" Click="btnEdit_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Content="Löschen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,171,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" Height="63" Click="btnDelete_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnHauptfenster" Content="Hauptfenster" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="481,243,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" Height="66" Click="btnHauptfenster_Click"/>
    <StatusBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="0,280,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="476">
        <Label x:Name="lblCount" Content="-" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </StatusBar>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtSuche" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="206,243,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="270" TextChanged="txtSuche_TextChanged"/>

</Grid>
```

I would be very happy if anyone can solve this. How I said I put in text in the search text box: txtSuche and nothing happens. Please don't be angry about my bad English I hope anyone can understand my text.

Great thanks in before.

Comment: I found the answer of this problem in the profile of : user:1506454 Great Thanks to you.